# How to pass in data from Models, into Table View Controller and then to DetailViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created quite a few classes and structs that have arrays from that data received from the end points of the Json API, and now I am in need of help passing in those arrays into a table view controller as well as a detail view controller that passes in the images and details from my model. Below are all of the models, "MealCategoryResponse", "MealDetailModel", "Meals" and MealDetailModel. I've included the Constants, as well as the ViewModels  that i've created for the data received from my API end points. How can I create a TableViewController that will list all of my Model as well as when the arrays of meals are clicked, take me to  detailViewController that has the details from my DetailModel? Please let me know if i need to add more information or if this question is not acceptable or if it needs to be edited. I am asking here because I have been trying to do this for the last days & I have covid.

```
    Constants that i've created to get the Url's link 


        import Foundation 
        struct Constants {
         struct Urls {
    
    
         static let mealsCategoriesUrl = URL(string: 
 "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php")!
    
    static func  getMealNameCategoryUrl(_ strMeal: String) -> URL {
        return URL(string:"https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef")!
    }
    
    static func  getMealByIdUrl(_ idMeal: String) -> URL { return URL(string:"https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52874")!
    }
}

static func getImagesUrl(strMealThumb: String) -> URL {
    return URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com//images//category//beef.png")!
}

struct strMealThumbUrl  {
    
    static let  strMealThumb = URL(string:"https://www.themealdb.com//images//media//meals//vtqxtu1511784197.jpg")!
}

struct strYoutubeUrl {
    
    let strYoutube = URL (string:
                            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMyBC9staMU")!
    
    
}
```

}

```
             Model with arrays  
            import Foundation 
    struct MealCategoryResponse: Decodable {
     let  categories: [MealCategory]
   }

   struct MealCategory: Decodable {
  let idCategory: String //id
  let strCategory: String //name
  let strCategoryThumb: String //image//
  let strCategoryDescription: String
 }


    import Foundation
     struct Meals: Decodable {
     let meals: [Meals]
     let strMeal: String
     let strMealThumb: String //image
     let idMeal: String

      }


      
         import Foundation
         struct MealDetailModel: Codable {
         let meals: [MealDetail]
          }
        struct MealDetail: Codable {
        let idMeal: String
        let strMeal: String
        let strCategory: String
        let strInstructions: String
        let strIngredient: String
        let strMeasure: String
        let strYoutube: String 
        let strMealThumb: String //image
       let meals: [[String: String?]]
      }



         ViewModels for passing in the data from API to the Model

       import Foundation 
       @MainActor
       class MealsListModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published public var mealsCategories: [CategoryMealViewModel] = []
        private func loadCategories(strCategory: String) async {
        do {
        let mealCategoryResponse = try await
```

WebServiceRequest().parseData(url: Constants.Urls.mealsCategoriesUrl) { data in
return try?   JSONDecoder().decode(MealCategoryResponse.self, from:data )
}

```
        self.mealsCategories = mealCategoryResponse.categories.map(CategoryMealViewModel.init)
        
       } catch {
        print(ServiceError.decocorrupt)
       }
    
    
       }
      }



       import Foundation
       import UIKit

      //create View model for meals Category
     struct CategoryMealViewModel: Identifiable {
     let id =  UUID()

    private let mealCategory: MealCategory

    init(_ mealCategory: MealCategory) {
    
    self.mealCategory = mealCategory
    
       }

       var strCategory: String {
        mealCategory.strCategory
      }
       var strCategoryThumb: URL? {
       URL(string: mealCategory.strCategoryThumb)
     }
     }
```

import Foundation
import UIKit
@MainActor

class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject{

```
@Published   var strMeal: String = ""
@Published   var strInstructions: String
@Published   var strIngredient: String
@Published   var strMeasure: String
@Published   var strMealThumb:URL?

init(strInstructions: String, strIngredient: String, strMeasure: String) {
    self.strInstructions = strInstructions
    self.strIngredient = strIngredient
    self.strMeasure = strMeasure
    
    
    func loadMealDetails(idMeal: String) async {
        do {
            let mealDetailResponse = try await  WebServiceRequest().parseData(url: Constants.Urls.getMealByIdUrl(strMeal)) { data in
                return try?   JSONDecoder().decode(MealDetailModel.self, from:data )
            }
            let mealDetail = mealDetailResponse.meals
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
       }
    
     }

   }
```

Comment: Did you get data by json decoding? I mean you got this data "mealDetail", "mealsCategories" ? If yes and you don't know how to show them in table view or collection view then you should learn UITableView or UICollectionView first.

Comment: Im just trying to figure out how to pass in my models into each Table view cell